# My function isn't recognized by my loop

Tags: r

I am trying to sample a population drawn from a normal distribution with a mean of 10.016 and a standard deviation of 0.8862719 (n=20), a thousand times. I want to create a loop to do this. I tried creating a function (stamendist) to draw random variables from a normal distribution with the abovementioned mean and standard deviation, but when I run the loop, I get an error message:
Error: could not find function "stamendist" (even though I ran the function before running the loop).

I tried running the loop without the object "stamendist" by just inputting rnorm(n=20,mean=10.016,sd=0.8862719), but the same error message persists.
Here is my code:

```
stamendist <- rnorm(n=20,mean=10.016,sd=0.8862719)
sampled.means <- NA 

for(i in 1:1000){
    y=stamendist(100)
    sampled.means[i] <- mean(y)
}
```

Am I misunderstanding how a function works?  I'm pretty new to R, so any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `stamendist` is a vector, not a function.. so `stamendist(100)` makes no sense

Comment: Initializing with `NA` pretty hacky, try initializing with  `sampled.means <- vector("numeric", 1e3L)`.  This allocates the exact amount of memory needed for the vector, whereas `NA` just builds a vector one-by-one.  If you know how big the vector is going to be, it's best to allocate its exact length.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a loop to obtain the vector of sample means:

```
n <- 1000
sampled.means <- colMeans(matrix(rnorm(n = 20 * n, 10.016, 0.8862719), ncol = n))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really great advice!  I know I didn't have to do a loop; I just wasn't sure how to use alternative methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `stamentdist` to be a function, you need to assign `stamendist` as a function.  The general notation for a function is:

```
foo <- function(args, ...){
    expressions
}
```

You must then decide which parameters you want the user to specify.  In your specific example, I assume you want the user to specify how many observations.  Here is how the function would look with that in mind:

```
stamendist <- function(n) {
  rnorm(n=n,mean=10.016,sd=0.8862719)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
stamendist <- rnorm(n=20,mean=10.016,sd=0.8862719)
```

You assign 20 values to the vector named `stamendist`

In this line:

```
y=stamendist(100)
```

You try to call a function stamendist, which doesnt exist.

Move this lineinside the loop:

```
stamendist <- rnorm(n=20,mean=10.016,sd=0.8862719)
```

So you create a new set of random number for each iteration.
Then pass `stamendist` to the mean function. And you dont need `y` at all

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful!